# using fopen to write in a txt in c language

Tags: c, fopen, dup2

I am studying computer science and I am supposed to create a c shell for a project.In this part of the project I have to write the code for these types of commands : "sort < in.txt > out.txt". My problem is that after using execlp so as to sort my "in.txt", i cannot write the result in the "out.txt" that I create. My code is like:

```
outfile = fopen("out.txt", "w");
dup2((int) outfile , 0);
dup2((int) outfile , 1);
close (outfile);
```

Does anyone know what I have to fix? Thank you.

Comment: why did not you check for the success of `fopen()`?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want to change the file descriptors 0 and 1 from stdin and stdout to your specific files. If so, use the standard [freopen](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/freopen/?kw=freopen).

Answer (score 0):

First you should use *open* instead of *fopen*. The cast of *outfile* to *int* is very wrong.
Second you have to open *in.txt*. The file descriptor for this file you should use for your first *dup2*.